# Python macro for LibreOffice - replace string in text

Tags: python, linux, scripting, libreoffice

I've been searching for a while for some user-friendly tutorial on this but with no luck.

I would like to write a macro in Python for LibreOffice, which would replace string in currently open document in Writer. Surprisingly, there doesn't seem to be any official guide, documentation or even examples, either from developers or users.

What I need to know is, **how can I in Python access the text of currently open document and change it**? Working example would be great but any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple "Hello World" example is as follows:

```
def hello():
    XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument().getText().setString("Hello!")

# Functions that can be called from Tools -> Macros -> Run Macro.
g_exportedScripts = hello,
```

See https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python/Transfer_from_Basic_to_Python.

How to search and replace text depends on your requirements.  Replace once or all occurrences?  Replace in ordinary text, or also in elements such as tables, frames or headers?  Case sensitive, or perhaps regular expressions?  See section 7.14 in [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) for examples in Basic.

Here is a working example in Python that changes all occurrences of "search for" to "change to":

```
document = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
search = document.createSearchDescriptor()
search.SearchString = "search for"
search.SearchAll = True
search.SearchWords = True
search.SearchCaseSensitive = False
selsFound = document.findAll(search)
if selsFound.getCount() == 0:
    return
for selIndex in range(0, selsFound.getCount()):
    selFound = selsFound.getByIndex(selIndex)
    selFound.setString("change to")
```

Comment: You are my hero ;) Not only the code works as promised but the link you provided is great as well! Thank you very much!